# Why are scabies mites not found everywhere on the host?

Tags: arachnology, parasitology

The distribution of scabies lesions is [not uniform](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Typical-distribution-of-scabies-lesions-a-Children-aged-2-years-and-adults-b_fig3_339131655). Sarcoptes Scabiei mites have an apparent preference for some places on human bodies.

They obviously prefer soft places, where they can burrow easily, but that's not the whole truth. For example, they generally avoid the face, even though there is plenty of soft skin to use. They burrow between fingers, but not on fingertips. They also completely ignore the scalp.

What factors are in play here? What makes mites so picky?